# Calculating the total of my purchase items

Tags: javascript, html, dom

i want to calculate the total of my purchase items by adding the sum of the purchases for each item(For exp: 2 shoes * price unit + 1 tshit * price unit) in front of "Shopping Bag total :"

here a description image : 
[image]

i already written a fonctionnal code that add/ remove products and also calculate the total purchase for each item. The last part of the code which is calculating the sum of my total purchase is not working.I'm confused and i don't know how to solve it.

Here the html5 code:

```
<div class="shopping-cart">
      <!-- Title -->
      <div class="title">
        Shopping Bag total : <input type="number" value="0" class="total-result-input" />
      </div>

      <!-- Product #1 -->
      <div class="item">
        <div class="buttons">
          <span class="delete-btn"></span>
          <span class="like-btn"></span>
        </div>

        <div class="image">
          <img src="item-1.png" alt="" />
        </div>

        <div class="description">
          <span>Common Projects</span>
          <span>Bball High</span>
          <span>White</span>
        </div>

        <div class="quantity">
          <button class="plus-btn" type="button" name="button""><img src="plus.svg" alt="" /></button>
          <input type="text" value="0" class="input-btn" />
          <button class="minus-btn" type="button" name="button"><img src="minus.svg" alt="" /></button>

        </div>

        <div class="total-price" id="549"><input type="number" value="0" class="result-btn" /></div>

      </div>

      <!-- Product #2 -->
      <div class="item">
        <div class="buttons">
          <span class="delete-btn"></span>
          <span class="like-btn"></span>
        </div>

        <div class="image">
          <img src="item-2.png" alt=""/>
        </div>

        <div class="description">
          <span>Maison Margiela</span>
          <span>Future Sneakers</span>
          <span>White</span>
        </div>

        <div class="quantity">
          <button class="plus-btn" type="button" name="button"><img src="plus.svg" alt="" /></button>
          <input type="text" value="0" class="input-btn" />
          <button class="minus-btn" type="button" name="button"><img src="minus.svg" alt="" /></button>
        </div>

        <div class="total-price" id="270"><input type="number" value="0" class="result-btn" /></div>
      </div>

      <!-- Product #3 -->
      <div class="item">
        <div class="buttons">
          <span class="delete-btn"></span>
          <span class="like-btn"></span>
        </div>

        <div class="image">
          <img src="item-3.png" alt="" />
        </div>

        <div class="description">
          <span>Our Legacy</span>
          <span>Brushed Scarf</span>
          <span>Brown</span>
        </div>

        <div class="quantity">
          <button class="plus-btn" type="button" name="button" ><img src="plus.svg" alt="" /></button>
          <input type="text" value="0" class="input-btn" />
          <button class="minus-btn" type="button" name="button"><img src="minus.svg" alt="" /></button>
        </div>

        <div class="total-price" id="349"><input type="number" value="0" class="result-btn" /></div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Here the JS code:

```
var items = document.querySelectorAll('.item');

items.forEach(function(item) {
  var minusButton = item.querySelector('.minus-btn');
  var plusButton = item.querySelector('.plus-btn');
  var inputField = item.querySelector('.input-btn');
  var resultField = item.querySelector('.result-btn');  

  minusButton.addEventListener('click', function minusProduct() {
    var currentValue = Number(inputField.value);
    if (currentValue > 0) {
      inputField.value = currentValue - 1;
      var x = item.querySelector('.total-price').id;
      resultField =  item.querySelector('.result-btn').value = x* inputField.value;
    } else inputField.value = 0

  });

  plusButton.addEventListener('click', function plusProduct() {
    var currentValue = Number(inputField.value);
    if (currentValue < 100) {
    inputField.value = currentValue + 1;
   var x = item.querySelector('.total-price').id;
   resultField = item.querySelector('.result-btn').value = Number(x)* Number(inputField.value);
  } else inputField.value = 100
  });

});

const results = document.querySelectorAll('.result-btn');
let total = 0;

results.forEach((result) => {

  total += result.value

});

document.querySelector('.total-result-input').value = total;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i just add

```
document.querySelector('.total-result-input').value = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll(".total-price > input")).reduce((acc, el) => acc + parseInt(el.value), 0)
```

inside of your `click` event and all will work good

```js
                var items = document.querySelectorAll('.item');

                items.forEach(function(item) {
                    var minusButton = item.querySelector('.minus-btn');
                    var plusButton = item.querySelector('.plus-btn');
                    var inputField = item.querySelector('.input-btn');
                    var resultField = item.querySelector('.result-btn');

                    minusButton.addEventListener('click', function minusProduct() {
                        var currentValue = Number(inputField.value);
                        if (currentValue > 0) {
                            inputField.value = currentValue - 1;
                            var x = item.querySelector('.total-price').id;
                            resultField = item.querySelector('.result-btn').value = x * inputField.value;

                            document.querySelector('.total-result-input').value = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll(".total-price > input")).reduce((acc, el) => acc + parseInt(el.value), 0)

                        } else inputField.value = 0

                    });


                    plusButton.addEventListener('click', function plusProduct() {
                        var currentValue = Number(inputField.value);
                        if (currentValue < 100) {
                            inputField.value = currentValue + 1;
                            var x = item.querySelector('.total-price').id;
                            resultField = item.querySelector('.result-btn').value = Number(x) * Number(inputField.value);
                            document.querySelector('.total-result-input').value = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll(".total-price > input")).reduce((acc, el) => acc + parseInt(el.value), 0)
                        } else inputField.value = 100
                    });



                });

                const results = document.querySelectorAll('.result-btn');
                let total = 0;

                results.forEach((result) => {

                    total += result.value

                });

                document.querySelector('.total-result-input').value = total;
```

```html
    <div class="shopping-cart">
        <!-- Title -->
        <div class="title">
            Shopping Bag total : <input type="number" value="0" class="total-result-input" />
        </div>
        <!-- Product #1 -->
        <div class="item">
            <div class="buttons">
                <span class="delete-btn"></span>
                <span class="like-btn"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="image">
                <img src="item-1.png" alt="" />
        </div>
                <div class="description">
                    <span>Common Projects</span>
                    <span>Bball High</span>
                    <span>White</span>
                </div>
                <div class="quantity">
                    <button class="plus-btn" type="button" name="button"">+</button>
                    <input type=" text" value="0" class="input-btn" />
                    <button class="minus-btn" type="button" name="button">-</button>
                </div>
                <div class="total-price" id="549"><input type="number" value="0" class="result-btn" /></div>
            </div>
            <!-- Product #2 -->
            <div class="item">
                <div class="buttons">
                    <span class="delete-btn"></span>
                    <span class="like-btn"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="image">
                    <img src="item-2.png" alt=""/>
        </div>
                    <div class="description">
                        <span>Maison Margiela</span>
                        <span>Future Sneakers</span>
                        <span>White</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="quantity">
                        <button class="plus-btn" type="button" name="button">+</button>
                        <input type="text" value="0" class="input-btn" />
                        <button class="minus-btn" type="button" name="button">-</button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="total-price" id="270"><input type="number" value="0" class="result-btn" /></div>
                </div>
                <!-- Product #3 -->
                <div class="item">
                    <div class="buttons">
                        <span class="delete-btn"></span>
                        <span class="like-btn"></span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="image">
                        <img src="item-3.png" alt="" />
        </div>
                        <div class="description">
                            <span>Our Legacy</span>
                            <span>Brushed Scarf</span>
                            <span>Brown</span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="quantity">
                            <button class="plus-btn" type="button" name="button">+</button>
                            <input type="text" value="0" class="input-btn" />
                            <button class="minus-btn" type="button" name="button">-</button>
                        </div>
                        <div class="total-price" id="349"><input type="number" value="0" class="result-btn" /></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Comment: the solution if fonctionnal but as a beginner developper can you explain me your written code please

Comment: 1st we need calc sum after every click and thats why i'm add code inside "click" event fuction
2nd [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll(".total-price > input")) <- how we get elements and prepare for iteration 
3rd .reduce((acc, el) => acc + parseInt(el.value), 0) sum all elements values

Answer (score 0):

```
const results = document.querySelectorAll('.result-btn');
let total = 0;

results.forEach((result) => {

   total += result.value

});
document.querySelector('.total-result-input').value = total;
```

Put it in a reasonable function and call this function on every change (plus, minus).